# How to do remote debugging in Eclipse CDT without running `gdbserver` manually on the target every time?

Tags: eclipse, gdb

Before each debugging cycle I have to run gdbserver on remote target (Linux). So I was thinking to make script that would call python program that would connect over ssh and would run gdbserver.

I cant find any options to run command before debug and I also try to change .gdbinit file but I am unable tu run python script whit that. Since I am using crosscompiler I cant to get other gdb whit such support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to run Python to invoke an external command from GDB. This (in .gdbinit) should work:

```
shell ssh remote-host gdbserver :12345 /path/to/binary/on/remote &
target remote remote-host:12345
```

If you do need more complicated ssh setup and need Python for that, you can certainly get it with

```
shell python your_script.py
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can't get any external program called from your gdbinit, I see one way of doing it within Eclipse that might work (I didn't tested) but it is not really straightforward...

- Create an External Tool configuration that launches your gdbserver program (Python or whatever command line script)
- Create a C/C++ application launcher that launch your application to debug
- Create a launch group that will call the two previously configured configurations.
- Launch the group in debug mode

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse 4.7.0 can connect to SSH and launch `gdbserver` automatically with the automatic launcher set when creating a new debug connection, without the need for any custom scripts.

I have explained the setup in great detail at: [Remote debugging C++ applications with Eclipse CDT/RSE/RDT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15685104/remote-debugging-c-applications-with-eclipse-cdt-rse-rdt/45658783#45658783)